# Async FastAPI production Dockerfile

Tags: python, asynchronous, dockerfile, fastapi, gunicorn

I am trying run my python FastApi app in async with this settings:

- gunicorn as worker manager
- uvicorn class as worker
- run in docker container
- async fastAPi

I am trying to run app in async mode but it works only in sync.

This is my basic api endpoint(there is asyncio.sleep for simulating some work):

```
@router.get("/info", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK, response_model=InfoReturn)
async def info():
    main_logger.info("BEFORE INFO")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    main_logger.info("AFTER INFO")
    return {
        "version": __VERSION__,
        "description": "Application for conquering the world !"
    }
```

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11.2-alpine3.17

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app && mkdir -p /etc/app
VOLUME ["/etc/app"]
WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY requirements.txt /opt/app

RUN set -e; \
    apk update && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        gcc \
        libc-dev \
        musl-dev \
        linux-headers \
        python3-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        openssl-dev \
    ; \
    pip install --upgrade pip; \
    pip install --ignore-installed --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt; \
    pip install "psycopg[binary,pool]"; \
    apk add vim; \
    apk --purge del .build-deps;

COPY [".", "/opt/app"]

CMD ["gunicorn", "run:app", "--workers", "4", "--worker-class", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

According to many sources, using gunicorn+uvicorn as worker is generaly used in production.
With these settings/code app is working but only in **sync** mode. For testing I put await asyncio.sleep(10) in endpoint and some logging msg. In development where I use only uvicorn everything works fine - you can call multiple times in one moment this endpoint url and it work in **async** mode but when I made docker container with gunicorn+uvicorn - it starts working in sync. If you try to call this endpoint in multiple times in one moment, first call is handled and second is waiting to end of first before starts.

So in log you can see something like this:

```
2023-03-14 13:37:38|testing_api|INFO|BEFORE INFO
2023-03-14 13:47:38|testing_api|INFO|AFTER INFO
2023-03-14 13:47:38|testing_api|INFO|BEFORE INFO
2023-03-14 13:57:38|testing_api|INFO|AFTER INFO
```

instead of:

```
2023-03-14 13:37:38|testing_api|INFO|BEFORE INFO
2023-03-14 13:37:38|testing_api|INFO|BEFORE INFO
2023-03-14 13:47:38|testing_api|INFO|AFTER INFO
2023-03-14 13:47:38|testing_api|INFO|AFTER INFO
```

Does anybody know how can I fix this please? What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Trying manual run(no docker) app with: uvicorn run:app --workers 4 or gunicorn run:app -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker and problem still occurs. App act as sync.

Answer (score 0):

can you try adding `"--worker-connections", "1000"` in cmd that can reduce queued up and process the request asynchronously https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-connections

Comment: That doesn't help.

Comment: Is it even possible to run gunicorn+uvicorn fastapi as async ?